# Xcode 8 Beta 6: storeViewController.loadProduct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, beta

What could be wrong with this line in Swift 3 that causes trying to build the app to fail...

```
storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: productparameters, completionBlock: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
})
```

I am not getting an error shown on that line. I am getting the "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" error. Within that error's log it points me to the line:

```
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/MyApp/MyViewController.swift:327:13 - line:331:14] RangeText="storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: productparameters, completionBlock: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            })"
```

If I comment that line out, the app builds and runs without problem.

---

The lines that come before it:

```
let storeViewController:SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();
storeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
storeViewController.delegate = self;

self.present(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);

let productparameters = [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:idString, SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken:affString, SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken:campString];
```

Comment: I tried your code in  xcode-beta1, Can able to built it. Could be a problem with beta6.

Comment: I don't have a solution as such but just some more debugging to try out. One thing to try is looking at your `productparameters` dictionary, could that be what is causing the crash? What happens for instance if you pass an empty dictionary instead?

Comment: Thanks @pbodsk! Passing in an empty productparameters dictionary of [String:Any]() made Xcode reveal the true error to me... which was that NSError needed to be changed to Error

Comment: @RanLearns great. Always nice when one error hides the real error :) (and now that we know the reason it kind of makes sense as all the NS prefixes are being dropped in Swift 3...kind of makes sense...kind of...if you squint :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing NSError with Error was the solution for me at this time.

```
storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: productparameters, completionBlock: { (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
})
```